# ZipException: zip END header not found in java-9

Tags: java, spring, javafx, java-9, javafx-9

**util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found**
exception when try to load javafx fxml view in java-9.

**Details**
My Application is a **Javafx**(uses **fxml view**) which is built and compiled using java-8(jdk-8 64-bit) and accessed as a WebStart with jre-9(64-bit).
Webpages(xhtml) are loaded and rendered in this javafx application.

**Also note that**
There are already two similar bugs reported (ie. JDK-8170276, JDK-8172872) and
these two bugs mentioned that the issue is not reproducible with latest java-9
but reproducible only with earlier java-9 ea build version.

**But in my case**, im using latest **java-9(9.0.4 version)** and
its always reproducible.

**Problem**
When i try to load fxml popup  after login, get below exceptions.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at jdk.deploy@9.0.1/com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.jar.DeployURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at jdk.deploy@9.0.1/com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.jar.DeployURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at client.FxmlWrapper.initialize(FxmlWrapper.java:57)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Suppressed: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache8046747560626483610.tmp
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

**Request if anyone could help on this issue,would be grateful.

Many Thanks.**

Although this is not the full code, but this is the code for showing fxml popup which throws "java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found" exceptions in java-9, but in java-8 works fine.

PopupAction.java

```
public class PopupAction  
{  
public PopupAction()
{
    super();
}

public void showPopup()
{
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Platform.runLater(
            new PopupHandler(latch, "testMsg", "testTitle", "testButtonText"));
    try
    {
        latch.await();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
    {

        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
}
```

PopupHandler.java

```
public class PopupHandler implements Runnable
{


private CountDownLatch latch;

private String message;

private String title;

private String buttonText;

public PopupHandler(CountDownLatch latch,
        String message, String title, String buttonText)
{

    this.latch = latch;
    this.message = message;
    this.title = title;
    this.buttonText = buttonText;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            Parent root;

                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                FXMLViewLoader fXMLViewLoader = new FXMLViewLoader("/fxmlView/warningPopup.fxml");
                root = fXMLViewLoader.getView();

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 110);
                scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setTitle(this.title);
                stage.initOwner(Application.getOwnerWindow());
                this.localAtomicBoolean.set(true);
                stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                stage.showAndWait();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.latch.countDown();
    }
}
}
```

FXMLViewLoader.java

```
   public final class FXMLViewLoader
   {
private FXMLLoader loader;

public FXMLViewLoader(String fxmlName)
{
    super();
    initialize(fxmlName);
}

private void initialize(String fxmlName)
{
    final URL resource = getResourceURL(fxmlName);
    this.loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);

    try
    {
        this.loader.load();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected URL getResourceURL(String fxmlName)
{
    return this.getClass().getResource(fxmlName);
}


public Parent getView()
{
    return this.loader.getRoot();
}

}
```

Comment: and whats the code?

Comment: Hi XtremeBaumer,  
Above is the code to show fxml popup.

Please note : it works standalone but does not work in our deployement   mode with java-9.  
We use Apache tomcat.  
Due to confidentiality not able to share the environmental information.
This issue happens only in java-9.  

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to clear the cache and clean install if its maven build