# Customize Spring boot ORM table column name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA. There is a class for JPA enitity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = SchemaConstant.MENU_TABLE)
public class Menu extends BaseEntity {

  @NotNull private String title;

  private String path;

  private UUID parentId;

  private boolean hasSub;

  private String iconName;
}
```

And the snapshot of the database table columns are shown below

[image]

If you see the table columns order is not the same as the class order. Now I want to reorder this table's columns.

```
Like column 1 -> id, column 2 -> title, column 3 -> icon_name as requires
```

**Is there any way of customizing the order of the table columns?**

Comment: Do you face the same issue if you build project outside IDE?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue in Android Studio also. @y.bedrov

Comment: Is it possible to provide full error stack?

Comment: This is the full error stack. @y.bedrov

Comment: Please try this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456298/2960034

Comment: I have tried with this, but it won't work.

Comment: What happens if you run gradle build task from command line?