# Importing project Not working in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

> I use Intellij  but when open a new project, it is  showing an issue
> Cause:zip END header not found
> [image]

> I Generated project from spring.io when importing that project into
> intellij I get  below type of issue

```
Cause: zip END header not found
```

Comment: maybe a quick search on Stack overflow would have saved you the time to write this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411697/intellij-compilation-error-zip-end-header-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ Compilation Error zip END header not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411697/intellij-compilation-error-zip-end-header-not-found)

Comment: Try to close the IDE, delete $HOME/.gradle directory, delete all .iml files and .idea folder from the project root directory and reimport the project from existing sources. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project .