# Cause: newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0) in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting errors in android studio, I tried all the possible steps but nothing helped me.
[Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.2.2, Gradle Version:7.2-rc-2 and JDK 15.0.2

Error Log File
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\asrar\Desktop\Smart GIT

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> newPosition < 0: (-1 < 0)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform work-runtime-2.5.0.aar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\asrar.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.work\work-runtime\2.5.0\b878e75e14ee7e745fe120bc78e8db8995064f4d\work-runtime-2.5.0.aar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar (androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=7, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\asrar.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a51d8e3d972cee1891837c926b3ae865\transformed\jetified-concurrent-futures-1.1.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2-rc-2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 34s
18 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 1 up-to-date

Answer (score 3):

Stacktrace and info is not a solution, just gives you more information about what went wrong.

Seems really similar to [IntelliJ Compilation Error zip END header not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411697/intellij-compilation-error-zip-end-header-not-found)

Which suggests your gradle cache is corrupted. Try clearing it. folder: $HOME/.gradle/caches

Comment: After 4 hours of searching for the problem, this is the only thing that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are some corrupted files.
For me invalidating caches and restart worked.

Last option here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The versions you're using for plugin version and Gradle are not compatible. According to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?

For Gradle Version 7.2 you need at least 7.1 Plugin version